# What ranges of $l$ and $m$ give the spherical harmonics for disk features?

Tags: models, spherical-harmonics, accretion-disk

The spherical harmonics represent a spherically symmetric basis and correspond to the eigenfunction solutions of the three-dimensional Laplacian. They take the form

$$ Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) = \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}}P_l^m(\cos\theta)e^{im\phi} $$

where

$$ P_l^m(x) = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^l l!}(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^{l+m}}{dx^{l+m}}(x^2-1)^l $$

and $|m|\leq l \geq 0$.

**What values for $m$ and $l$ can be reasonably used to approximate disk-like features in a model?** For example, I'd like to be able to model shapes like this:

[image: Source: ALMA]

(image source: ALMA)

Comment: Why not use the bessel functions instead?

Comment: @Triatticus I'm definitely not opposed! Can you elaborate a little bit? I'm less familiar with using Bessel functions to parameterize 3D models.